# Android how to achieve this type of layout with rows and col span

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, grid-layout, staggered-gridview

[image]

[image]

Requirement:

- I should be able to scroll entire view if left view is visible or not (all components should scroll at a time if i scroll anywhere with in the view).
- By clicking on show/hide left view button button it should be able to hide or show left view.
- In cell (only cell not left view) there is a expand/collapse functionality (i can increase/decrease
  cell height)
- And If i change font size in device settings app, it should be effect here also(So supporting dynamic font size)

Comment: constraintlayout with visibility gone initially for your "left view" and then make visisble using your button, it's trivial

Comment: use a `DrawerLayout` instead of wasting lots of precious screen estate ...

Answer (score -1):

Navigation drawer + Recycler view is a good solution.

Alternatively to the navigation drawer you can just use a ConstraintLayout that contains your header, left and RecyclerView.

> I should be able to scroll entire view if left view is visible or not (all components should scroll at a time if i scroll anywhere with in the view).

That will be resolved by the recycler view itself.

> By clicking on show/hide left view button button it should be able to hide or show left view.

Just toggle the visibility of your left view when clicking the button, use something like:

```
public void toggleLeftViewVisible() {
    int visibility = leftView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE;
    leftView.setVisibility(visibility);
}
```

> In cell (only cell not left view) there is a expand/collapse functionality (i can increase/decrease cell height)

Resolve that by adding a click listener (maybe on a button or on the view itself) inside your recycler view adapter.

> And If i change font size in device settings app, it should be effect here also(So supporting dynamic font size)

If you do the right implementation this should be taken care automatically by Android.

Comment: If we use navigation drawer, when we scroll recycler view even left view(navigation drawer) should also scroll along with recycler view.  Is it possible when we use Navigation drawer + Recycler view combination.